# require shim setup- jquery.flot/jquery.flot.selection

Tags: javascript, requirejs, flot, shim

So I'm working with jquery.flot and jquery.flot.selection and since define({... loads modules asynchronously I am having a problem because the selection plugin is trying to push itself into $.plot.plugins (which is created by jquery.flot) but at that moment $.plot.plugins still isn't defined.

I found that the "shim" argument in require.config should help me with this but I am having no luck...
so here's the rundown...
jquery.flot creates $.plot
and jquery.flot.selection adds itself to $.plot.plugins

what I've tried...

```
shim:{
    'js/lib/jquery.flot':{
        exports:'$.plot'
    },
    'js/lib/jquery.flot.selection':{
        deps:['js/lib/jquery.flot']
    }
}
```

also

```
shim:{
    'js/lib/jquery.flot.selection':['js/lib/jquery.flot']
}
```

my plugin looks like this..

```
define(['jquery','lib/jquery.flot','lib/jquery.flot.selection'], function() {
(function($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition
.....
```

I also tried

```
define(['jquery'],function(){
require[('js/lib/jquery.flot.selection'],function(){
//jQuery plugin definition
...
```

What should I do???

Comment: It turns out I'm using RequireJs 1.0.4, so I can't rely on shim...What can I do?

Comment: Shim was inspired by Use.js which is a plugin for 1.x - http://tbranyen.com/post/amdrequirejs-shim-plugin-for-loading-incompatible-javascript

Comment: Awesome! so I added this to my plugin "define(["jquery","lib/jquery.flot","lib/use!lib/jquery.flot.selection"],"
and this to my local require " 
paths:{
...
        use : '../../../../otherDirec/src/main/webapp/js/lib/use'
},
   use:{
        "../../../../otherDirec/src/main/webapp/js/lib/jquery.flot.selection":{
            deps:["use!../../../../otherDirec/src/main/webapp/js/lib/jquery.flot"]
        }
    }"
and I still get an error saying Module 'lib/jquery.flot.selection' is undefined or does not have a `use` config. Make sure it exists, add a `use` config, or don't use use! on it

Comment: should I close this and open another topic in regards to troubleshooting use.js setup?

Comment: Might be easier yeah, I'll take a look when you have

Comment: I have the same problem.  Am eagerly awaiting a good solution.

Comment: Fixed, turns out I was updating the wrong require.config... @Mark create a new topic to see if we can guide you through it, I know how stressful It can be ;)

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who happens to run into this in the future, RequireJS can be a little opaque when it comes to diagnosing problems. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/2rV9P/3/) a working example of RequireJS 2 with jquery.flot and jquery.flot.selection, without the use module.

It's a little hard to tell what's different between this example and the question above, thus the opaqueness!

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
            'jquery.flot': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: '$.plot'
        },
            'jquery.flot.selection': {
            deps: ['jquery.flot']
        }
    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min',
            'jquery.flot': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.1/jquery.flot.min',
            'jquery.flot.selection': 'https://raw.github.com/flot/flot/master/jquery.flot.selection'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'jquery.flot', 'jquery.flot.selection'], function ($) {
    // jQuery plugin definition
    console.log($.plot);
    $('#x').text($.plot.plugins);
});
```